# Setting Icon on JButton causes NPE

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, icons, jbutton, imageicon

This is my first attempt to use a GUI and I am trying to set the Icon of a JButton. No matter how I code it I get a NPE. I have marked the line where the NPE occurs. I have had success in passing the URL to the setIcon method, but it never affects the GUI. I have also tried this code using Icon instead of Image Icon with no change. Any advice would be very helpful. Thanks.

```
static Random roll = new Random();

handCard1 = new javax.swing.JButton();       //this has been initialized through a series of methods that initialized the GUI

public static void main(String args[]) 
{

    yourHand.setCard1(rollForCard.getCard());         //randomly set to fire, water or wind


    if (yourHand.getCard1().equals("fire"))

            handCard1.setIcon(SetIcon.setFireIcon()); //NPE here



           //I also tried a simple       handCard1.setIcon(fire);
           //with this before the main   ImageIcon fire = new ImageIcon("fire.jpg");

}//end main
```

SetIcon...

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class SetIcon 
{

public static ImageIcon setFireIcon()
{
    ImageIcon fire = (new ImageIcon("fire.jpg"));

    //I have also tried: ImageIcon fire = (new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("fire.jpg")));
    //and:           ImageIcon fire = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("fire.jpg")));
    return fire;
}

}
```

Comment: Two things jump to mind.  1- `hardCard1` is `null` or 2- `fire` icon is null.  I would recommned using `ImageIO` over using `ImageIcon` as you will get better feedback if the file can't be read.  Also remember `ImageIcon(String)` translates the `String` to a file reference. If the icon is embedded, this will not work.  Also, having looked over the code properly know, I can't see how your program could actually compile.  You're accessing `handCard1` from a `static` context while `handCard1` is not `static`...

Comment: I attempted to make handCard1 static but I get "handCard1 cannot be resolved to a type".

Comment: I "guess" it should read `private static JButton handCard1 = new javax.swing.JButton();` instead?

Comment: Icon, ImageIcon by default never caused any exceptions, you have to test if isn't null, issue is somewhere in the rest of your code

Answer (score 0):

well, your handCard1 might be a non static variable while your icon setting procedure is being done in a static method. 
Usually we use main method to instance objects, and this is what you should do, make a new instance of the class and move the cod in the constructor and your NPE will disappear or declare handCard1 as static.
EDIT1:
Also if your handCard1 is already static, NPE probably appears because of the wrong path in your setIcon method, that icon must be placed in your java.exe dir if you didn't setup any classpaths. best way to fix this is to import that image into your eclipse/netbeans project as a resource and to access it as a resource path.

Comment: What are you referring to when you say move the cod?

Comment: nevermind, handCard1 must be static if compiler doesn't give an error, so the problem is from that path you are using. read my edit.

Comment: something like return new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/resource/fire.jpg"))                 ,where resource is the folder containing your pic